# Disadvantage of PHP file system based chat system

Tags: php, chat

I want to implement Chat system on my website where users can interact with each other in rooms. This is my first time when I am implementing chat system.

On searching, I found that [phpFreeChat](http://www.phpfreechat.net/) is a good option but on going through its introduction I found that it doesn't use DB at all. So I am wondering, how good in its performance and how much is it flexible as compared to any DB-based approach.

Anyone who have used can please give a viewpoint whether I should go for phpFreeChat so after that I can start learning more about. The website has a huge traffic of around 3 million visits per month.

Comment: I am not an expert in implementing chat but with a 3 million users on a db chat will be a huge load on the db. Socket will be a good approach. Or an IP chat implementation.

Comment: I don't know phpFreeChat at all, but in the 4 minutes since you posted the question, I learned that *by default* it uses the file system (probably for portability), but it *can* work with MySQL too.

Answer (score 2):

Any *pull* based chat system (in which the clients will have to actively contact the server to ask for updates) is hugely resource intensive. Every client will make a request every so many seconds; multiply that by the number of clients and you're very soon DDoSing your own server.

A proper system should be *push* based, in which every client has a persistent connection to the server and the server is able to push messages to all relevant parties in realtime. This is perfectly possible using web sockets or long poll as fallback. A pub/sub protocol like [WAMP](http://wamp.ws) is perfect for this use, as are more specialised protocols like [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/?search=XMPP).

Writing to a file or database is entirely unnecessary and would only be a secondary feature for the purpose of data persistence. The server just needs to be a *message broker*, storage is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need - my first chat application was also file based and it was (and still is) pretty quick, but customizing and adding new functions is a pain in the ass. If your only need is to have quick chat without complex functions, go for file based. If you need to make user rights and other complex things, go for database based system.